# Can't launch Java program from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I can't run my Java code without getting this error message:

> An internal error occurred during: "Launching thing".
>
> org/eclipse/jdt/debug/core/JDIDebugModel

Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class thing {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    
        String f = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("First number: ");
        String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Second Number: ");
    
        int first = Integer.parseInt(f);
        int second = Integer.parseInt(s);
        int sum = first + second;
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Answer: " + sum, "Title", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

**Error Log:**

[image]

**Which contains:**

```
eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.7.0_01
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

This is a continuation of log file C:\Users\Cole\workspace\.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2012-02-05 13:11:35.180

Error
Sun Feb 05 13:11:55 CST 2012
Plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaApplicationLaunchShortcut.

org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui (259).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.getDelegate(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.getLaunchableResource(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.LaunchingResourceManager.getLaunchableResource(LaunchingResourceManager.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.ContextRunner.selectAndLaunch(ContextRunner.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.ContextRunner.launch(ContextRunner.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.AbstractLaunchToolbarAction.run(AbstractLaunchToolbarAction.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.AbstractLaunchHistoryAction.runWithEvent(AbstractLaunchHistoryAction.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$6.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.JDIDebugUIPlugin for bundle org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/debug/core/IJavaHotCodeReplaceListener
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:166)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jdt.debug.core.IJavaHotCodeReplaceListener
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 63 more
```

**What's happening here?**

Comment: can you start Eclipse with -clean paramater? Seems like some bundle is not correctly loaded. I just tried myself the code and seems to work fine..

Comment: It seems `jdimodel.jar` is missing from your bundle.Check here `eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.debug_3.7.0.v20110509`.

Comment: The code is not the problem (it runs fine in my computer). You're not posting enough information to troubleshoot your problem. What version of Eclipse? What version of the JDK? Can you give us a step by step walkthrough?

Comment: I had a similar issue and the answer was in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250388/error-open-debug-in-preferences-in-eclipse

sudo apt-get --reinstall install tzdata-java

Comment: It's very strange, but adding "-Dcom.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.DefaultTimeZoneType=ICU" to eclipse.ini solved this problem for me