# Error opening Debug in Preferences in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I got this error when I opened the Debug tab inside the Preferences in Eclipse, Does anyone know what happened?

ps:. This happened after I did the Update.

[image: Debug Preferences]
EDIT:

```
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2012-02-12 15:21:50.290
!MESSAGE Plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaApplicationLaunchShortcut.
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui (258).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.getDelegate(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.getLaunchableResource(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.LaunchingResourceManager.getLaunchableResource(LaunchingResourceManager.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.ContextRunner.selectAndLaunch(ContextRunner.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.ContextRunner.selectAndLaunch(ContextRunner.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.ContextRunner.launch(ContextRunner.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.AbstractLaunchToolbarAction.run(AbstractLaunchToolbarAction.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.AbstractLaunchHistoryAction.runWithEvent(AbstractLaunchHistoryAction.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$6.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.JDIDebugUIPlugin for bundle org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/debug/core/IJavaHotCodeReplaceListener
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:166)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jdt.debug.core.IJavaHotCodeReplaceListener
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 65 more
```

Comment: Please update the question with clicking on details. Also, please take a look at the end of the `.metadata/.log` file in your workspace root.

Comment: @rlegendi The details contain exactly what the picture above has "Unable to create the selected preference page.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui (258)." In log file I can't understood the error.

Comment: Can you pastebin the corresponding stacktrace or google it for some hints? Also, try running eclipse with the `-clean` switch.

Comment: Ok, look the full StackTrace error.

Answer (score 14):

I had this problem on Ubuntu 12.04 after OpenJDK was updated.
Found solution here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/186986/eclipse-has-multiple-issues-after-jre-6-openjdk-upgrade

Just run:

> sudo apt-get --reinstall install tzdata-java

Comment: me too, once I woke up and realised that 'just run' was not part of it :)

Comment: What's the WindowsXP equivalent of this? I'm seeing a very similar problem in RAD 8.5 on WinXP... The only change I've made recently is installing the Groovy plugins, haven't touched anything else.

Comment: Also, it appears that the OP is running Windows 7 (based on their screen shot), so telling them to run `apt-get` is probably not relevant to their situation.

Comment: For Windows users, there is another solution. Open eclipse.ini in the Eclipse installation folder and add `-Dcom.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.DefaultTimeZoneType=ICU` as the last line of that file.

Answer (score 5):

same problem happened in my windows 8..

solution :

just restart the IDE the problem will get resolved .

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a similar issue was discussed here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/156204/530834/

Seems like deleting the file ".metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap" could fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem on Mac OS X 10.5.8 running on an old PPC "cheese grater" after upgrading Eclipse 4.3 / Kepler to run on OpenJDK 1.7.  Hit it on the Installed JREs tab.

I found the answer in https://askubuntu.com/questions/186986/eclipse-has-multiple-issues-after-jre-6-openjdk-upgrade.  Add the following to end of your eclipse.ini:

```
-Dcom.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.DefaultTimeZoneType=ICU
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by changing permission recursively on the STS directory and then changing the eclipse default jre to point to my java installation.

Answer (score 0):

On linux system, such problems happen, when eclipse has problem accessing JVM, i.e. no permission to access the jre/jdk dir. so fix file permission will help.